# How to find the path of files in a directory from a column of a CSV (PYTHON)

Tags: python, csv, path, find

I have a csv file in which there is a column with multiples values. I'm trying to find in a root directory with multiple subdirectories all files what names start with each value of the column and return the path where those files are and write them on a csv. For example: the first value of the column is 'linux' so if I had two files named 'linux01.jpg' and 'linuximg.jpg' the function would return the two paths in a csv.
Thats what i have for now and my csv is blank. Thank you.

```
import csv
import os, fnmatch


def find(pattern, path):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result

ifile = open('carte.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(ifile)
ofile = open('output.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter='\t')
for row in reader:
    find_key = find(row[3], '/home/ro/Desktop/search/IDBUF')
    if find_key != None:
        writer.writerow(find_key)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not surprising that your output CSV is blank, or rather contains a newline for each line of your input CSV.

The following line is the problem:

```
find_key = find(row[3], '/home/ro/Desktop/search/IDBUF')
```

in your example `row[3]` evaluates in `'linux'` and you will find files which names are exactly `'linux'`. If you want to find all the file which names can be `'linux01.jpg'` or `'linuximg.jpg'` change the previous line to:

```
find_key = find('*' + row[3] + '*', '/home/ro/Desktop/search/IDBUF')
```

An other solution is to write `*linux*` instead of `linux` in your input CSV file.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I would also change the line ``if find_key != None:`` to ``if find_key != None and find_key != []:`` to avoid empty lines in the output CSV file.